# Enable button inside fieldlayout in XamDatagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a xamnumericeditor in my first column and a button in my 4th column. I want to Enable the button when user edits the xamnumericeditor in first column.

I want to do it from code behind, also i have method call "Cellupdated" which is called as soon as the user edits the cell.

the button is inside a fieldlayout .

Xaml of Fieldslayout

```
<Style x:Key="buttonInCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                        <Button  x:Name="btnRemoveCommands" Click="Button_Click" Width="50" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                            <Image  Source="..\Resources\delete.png"  Stretch="UniformToFill"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Width="16"/>
                                <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext.DataItem.RemoveCommandsVisibility}"  Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext.DataItem.RemoveCommandsVisibility}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext.DataItem.CurrentValueNullable,Mode=TwoWay}"  Value="{x:Null}">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>-->

                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
                   </Style>



private void dtgAdmin_CellUpdated(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.CellUpdatedEventArgs e)
{

//need to disable the button here

}

  <igDP:FieldLayout>
                    <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                        <igDP:Field Name="Description"   Label="{LocText Key=HeaderParameter, Assembly=Sample}">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings CellMinWidth="100"  CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource NormalCellStyle}" AllowEdit="False" />
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                        <igDP:Field Name="CurrentValueNullable" Label="{LocText Key=HeaderCurrentValue, Assembly=Sample}">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings EditorStyle="{StaticResource EditCellStyle}" EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamNumericEditor}" EditAsType="{x:Type sys:Int16}" CellMinWidth="50"  />
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                        <igDP:Field Name="MinValueStr"  Label="{LocText Key=HeaderMinValue, Assembly=Sample}">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings CellMinWidth="50" CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource NormalCellStyle}" AllowEdit="False" />
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                        <igDP:Field Name="MaxValueStr"  Label="{LocText Key=HeaderMaxValue, Assembly=Sample}">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings  Width="50" CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource NormalCellStyle}" AllowEdit="False" />
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>

                        <igDP:Field Name="RemoveCommands"  Label="Clear">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings  Width="16" CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource buttonInCellStyle}" />
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
```

Comment: Is XamDataGrid from infragistics? Have you considered posting this question on their forums?

Comment: yes it is from infragistics , i have posted the question but waiting for a reply since yesterday.

Comment: Where is buttonInCellStyle defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind a `ICommand` to your button, you can control the button Enabled property through the CanExecute method. If the method returns true the button turns enabled, otherwise turns disabled.

Prism offers out of the box the `DelegateCommand` that turns easy the implementation of commands.